# How to properly terminate a connection using `mysql` package in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a silly question but it occupied my mind.

I've implemented an API in Node.js using `mysql` package installed for the project.
I used it as this:

```js
// Creating Connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: database,
    multipleStatements: true,
});

// An Endpoint
router.get("/getAll", function (_, res) {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM admin", (error, data) => {
    if (!error)
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        data,
      });
  });
});

...
```

It works but my question is: I wouldn't face any connection problem? Because I don't close the connection and there are other endpoints.

If I should close it, can you please give me an example? Because I used `connection.end()` and it throws some errors which I don't remember currently.

Thanks

Comment: The only problems I've seen related to `connection.end()` are if you do it multiple times, or do it prematurely. You must wait until everything has finished using the connection. Since queries are asynchronous, that generally means it must be in the last callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, since mysql persists for the lifetime of the application, you don't need to close it manually unless the application crashes or exits. For web applications that handle large volumes of requests, frequently opening and close mysql can affect performance. a better approach is to use a connection pool that will automatically open and close connections as needed.

```
//process exit
process.on('exit', (code) => {
    if (connection) {
    connection.end(error => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error ending the connection: ', error);
      } else {
        console.log('MySQL connection ended successfully');
      }
    });
  }
});

//uncaughtException
process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
    if (connection) {
    connection.end(error => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error ending the connection: ', error);
      } else {
        console.log('MySQL connection ended successfully');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```
//use connection pool
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```